# open UIActivityViewController after UIAlertController fails

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I need to have a function, to share some .csv files via e-mail.

So first I am going to save the .csv files to the document directory and afterwards I am trying to open an UIActivityViewController.

But this fails.

This is my code:

```
saveprojectfile() // Here are the UIAlertController calls, these calls needs some time

let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [path], applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completeion: nil)
```

Any hints, why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIActivityViewController` code is being executed while the `UIAlertController` is displayed, but it cannot present while the alert controller is displayed. I would have thought this would crash.

You should display the activity view controller in the completion handler of the alert controller action.

```
// Code for alert controller (was in your saveprojectfile() function
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: yourFunction)) // OK action handler added
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) // Completion handler here will not work as it fires on completion of presenting, not dismissing

func yourFunction() {
    // Present the action controller here
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [path], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completeion: nil)
}
```

Comment: @Manuel No problem! :)